# Aggregate calculations with and without grouping variable in data.table

Tags: r, data.table

I'm producing some summary statistics at the by-group and overall levels.

(Note: the overall statistic cannot necessarily be derived from the group-level stats.  A weighted average could work, but not a median.)

Thus far my workarounds use `rbindlist` on either summary stats or copies of the original data, as in:

```
library(data.table)
data(iris)

d <- data.table(iris)

# Approach 1)

rbindlist(list(d[, lapply(.SD, median),  by=Species, .SDcols=c('Sepal.Length','Petal.Length')],
               d[, lapply(.SD, median),  .SDcols=c('Sepal.Length', 'Petal.Length')]),
      fill=TRUE)
#       Species Sepal.Length Petal.Length
# 1:     setosa          5.0         1.50
# 2: versicolor          5.9         4.35
# 3:  virginica          6.5         5.55
# 4:         NA          5.8         4.35

# Approach 2)

d2 <- rbindlist(list(copy(d), copy(d[,Species:="Overall"]) ) )
d2[, lapply(.SD, median),  by=Species, .SDcols=c('Sepal.Length', 'Petal.Length')]
#       Species Sepal.Length Petal.Length
# 1:     setosa          5.0         1.50
# 2: versicolor          5.9         4.35
# 3:  virginica          6.5         5.55
# 4:    Overall          5.8         4.35
```

The first approach seems to be faster (avoids copies).

The second approach allows me to use a label "Overall" instead of the `NA` fill, which is more intelligible if some records were missing the "Species" value (which in the first approach would result in two rows of `NA` Species.)

Are there any other solutions I should consider?

Comment: With the first approach, you don't need to fill if you use `c(list(Species="Overall"), lapply(.SD, median))`

Comment: `rbind` has the same `fill` argument - there is no need to do that awkward `rbindlist(list(` construction

Comment: @Frank that's true, and you don't need `list` in that either.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think I normally do it like this:

```
cols = c('Sepal.Length','Petal.Length')

rbind(d[, lapply(.SD, median), by=Species, .SDcols=cols],
      d[, lapply(.SD, median), .SDcols=cols][, Species := 'Overall'])
#      Species Sepal.Length Petal.Length
#1:     setosa          5.0         1.50
#2: versicolor          5.9         4.35
#3:  virginica          6.5         5.55
#4:    Overall          5.8         4.35
```

Comment: This answer clued me into two things.  First the reminder that `data.table::rbind` is essentially the same as `rbindlist` (at least it is now, `?rbindlist` is not clear on earlier versions).  More importantly, I was creating a copy to avoid editing `d` by reference, but I could have just added a secondary calculation `[, Species := ...]`.  Many thanks.

Answer (score 2):

I accepted @Eddi's answer but wanted to incorporate the good comment from @Frank.  This approach IMO makes the most sense.

```
library(data.table)
d <- data.table(iris)
cols = c('Sepal.Length','Petal.Length')

rbind(d[, lapply(.SD, median), by=Species, .SDcols=cols],
      d[, c(Species = 'Overall', lapply(.SD, median) ), .SDcols=cols])
#       Species Sepal.Length Petal.Length
# 1:     setosa          5.0         1.50
# 2: versicolor          5.9         4.35
# 3:  virginica          6.5         5.55
# 4:    Overall          5.8         4.35
```

It may also be slightly faster (1.54 vs. 1.73 millis on `microbenchmark`) than applying the secondary calculation.